# window.open browser closing automatically

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am opening the page in separate browser with window.open("URL") and closing it with window.close() once users finish the activity. So my question is if Users opens the page with window.open("URL") and don't do anything, is it possible to have timer so that that tab/page get close itself ??????

Comment: Yes. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan so i can just put setTimeout and window.close init with conditions ?

Comment: @HarunYilmaz thank you guys for quick response and yes your comments answered my question. Thank you so much

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thank you guys for quick response and yes your comments answered my question. Thank you so much